# Splitting/Cutting an STL file with Python

Tags: python, stl-format

I have an .stl file with z-coordinates from 0 to ~200 (x and y don't matter) and I would like to cut it in z-direction in order to get a smaller one (e.g. with z-coordinates from 0 to 50). (Please see Image 1 - red line has nothing to do with it, it is used for another purpose)

Now I'm using NetFabb software (https://www.netfabb.com/blog/netfabb-basic-now-just-netfabb) and it works very well (Please see Image 2). 
Since I'm coding with Python and I'm using that "original" .stl file in my Python code, would be useful to have a code to cut this .stl and to generate a new .stl file from the original one, without using any external software.

Does anybody know how I could do it? Or does already exist python function to do it?

**Image 1 - "Original" big .stl file, that need to be cut (MatLab picture):**

[image: Image 1 - "Original" big .stl file, that need to be cut (MatLab picture)]

**Image 2 - Splitted/Cut .stl with NetFabb (MatLab picture):**

[image: Image 2 - Splitted/Cut .stl with NetFabb (MatLab picture)]

[DropBox link for downloading original .stl file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ymkcd1tf5zn0stn/99perc.stl?dl=0)

[cut stl form another point of view... donut shape is still there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuwaE.png)

Comment: Please can you edit your question and add a sample from this STL file?

Comment: I could not attache it, so I put the dropbox link to download it. Hope it works

Comment: Looks like binary format. It will be hard to parse it by hand in Python, I think...

Comment: I think so, that's why I'm looking for packages/modules/functions that can do it...

Comment: Just googling around gave me (https://github.com/WoLpH/numpy-stl), (http://python-stl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and (https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I've already tried them but numpy-stl and python-stl don't have method to cut .stl files. Pymesh has it (not 100% sure), but I can't install it in PyCharm (don't know why)

Comment: Out of curiousity: your input model has a hole through it (topologically, it is a donut) but the hole seems to be closed in Image 2. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I added a new picture: as you can see the donut shape is still there, except for the layer where the original .stl has been cut. Do you have any suggestion about cutting an .stl with a python code?

Comment: Interesting that that's what you want. I would even guess that actually it is not "the layer where the original .stl has been cut" but two layers at the same z-coordinate.

In your situation the most reasonable solution seems to find out, how to make Pymesh run on your computer. If that really is impossible, you could consider coding it yourself: after all, the algorithm should not be that difficult.